# Как сделать чат в глобальной сети c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, сокет, winsock

Есть Server и Client(можно открыть несколько и передавать сообщения от одного другому), работает в локальной сети, как сделать что бы можно было отправлять сообщения в глобальной сети?

// Server

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

SOCKET Connections[100];
int Counter = 0;

enum Packet {
    P_ChatMessage,
    P_Test
};

bool ProcessPacket(int index, Packet packettype) {
    switch (packettype) {
    case P_ChatMessage:
    {
        int msg_size;
        recv(Connections[index], (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
        char* msg = new char[msg_size + 1];
        msg[msg_size] = '\0';
        recv(Connections[index], msg, msg_size, NULL);
        for (int i = 0; i < Counter; i++) {
            if (i == index) {
                continue;
            }

            Packet msgtype = P_ChatMessage;
            send(Connections[i], (char*)& msgtype, sizeof(Packet), NULL);
            send(Connections[i], (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
            send(Connections[i], msg, msg_size, NULL);
        }
        delete[] msg;
        break;
    }
    default:
        std::cout << "Unrecognized packet: " << packettype << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    return true;
}

void ClientHandler(int index) {
    Packet packettype;
    while (true) {
        recv(Connections[index], (char*)& packettype, sizeof(Packet), NULL);

        if (!ProcessPacket(index, packettype)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    closesocket(Connections[index]);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //WSAStartup
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)& addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

    SOCKET newConnection;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)& addr, &sizeofaddr);

        if (newConnection == 0) {
            std::cout << "Error #2\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Client Connected!\n";
            std::string msg = "Hello. It`s my first network program!";
            int msg_size = msg.size();
            Packet msgtype = P_ChatMessage;
            send(newConnection, (char*)& msgtype, sizeof(Packet), NULL);
            send(newConnection, (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
            send(newConnection, msg.c_str(), msg_size, NULL);

            Connections[i] = newConnection;
            Counter++;
            CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ClientHandler, (LPVOID)(i), NULL, NULL);

            Packet testpacket = P_Test;
            send(newConnection, (char*)& testpacket, sizeof(Packet), NULL);
        }
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

// Client

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

SOCKET Connection;

enum Packet {
    P_ChatMessage,
    P_Test
};

bool ProcessPacket(Packet packettype) {
    switch (packettype) {
    case P_ChatMessage:
    {
        int msg_size;
        recv(Connection, (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
        char* msg = new char[msg_size + 1];
        msg[msg_size] = '\0';
        recv(Connection, msg, msg_size, NULL);
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        delete[] msg;
        break;
    }
    case P_Test:
        std::cout << "Test packet.\n";
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Unrecognized packet: " << packettype << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    return true;
}

void ClientHandler() {
    Packet packettype;
    while (true) {
        recv(Connection, (char*)& packettype, sizeof(Packet), NULL);

        if (!ProcessPacket(packettype)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    closesocket(Connection);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //WSAStartup
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)& addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error: failed connect to server.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Connected!\n";

    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ClientHandler, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    std::string msg1;
    while (true) {
        std::getline(std::cin, msg1);
        int msg_size = msg1.size();
        Packet packettype = P_ChatMessage;
        send(Connection, (char*)& packettype, sizeof(Packet), NULL);
        send(Connection, (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
        send(Connection, msg1.c_str(), msg_size, NULL);
        Sleep(10);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: По идее нужно вместо `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");` написать `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);` или вместо 127.0.0.1 написать ip сетевой карты. Также открыть порт в братмауере. В прочем, для тестов проще его выключить полностью. И если компьютер под nat, прокинуть порты на роутере.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко а проброс портов нужно делать только на машине где будет сервер, или и на машине на которой клиент? при условии что они не находятся в одной локальной сети

Comment: Только на машине, где есть сервер. Проброс нужен только для входящих соединений (сервера). Для исходящих (клиент) роутер автоматически пробрасывает произвольный свободный порт до завершения соединения. Nat называется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такс, если вы хотите сделать так чтобы, вы сидели дома и сервер был у вас на компьютере и к вам кто-либо подсоединился, то так не получится, почему? 
Потому что у вас IP не уникальный.

Вам нужно пробиться через NAT и ето задача далеко не тривиальная, тем боллее для ТСР протокола (TCP Hole punching ), вообще, для вещей по типу P2P соединения, посмотрите в сторону UPNP протокола.

Если же вам надо загрузить сервер на сервис типа Azure то, здесь задача попроще, так как теоретически у "облака" есть белый IP, что позволит Вам приконектиться, впрочем тут есть еще куча нюансов, таких как фаервол "облака" и так даллее.

http://bford.info/pub/net/rfc5128.txt